# How can I get data back from a dynamic call to OPENROWSET?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, openrowset

One strange attribute of T-SQL's `OPENROWSET()` function is that it cannot accept parameters within the 'query' which it executes remotely.  In order to get around this I guess you have to create a long string containing the `OPENROWSET` calls and the parametrized query.

Given this limitation, I'm trying to get this piece of code to work:

```
Declare @DataId int
Declare @RecordType varchar(50)
Declare @Filter varchar(50)

 -- ...

SELECT TOP 1 
    @RecordType = recordType,
    @DataId = DataId
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
                'Server=MyServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                'SELECT recordType, DataId FROM MyDb..data_lookup
                 WHERE Filter = ''' + @Filter+'''')
```

This throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near '+'

Right now, which makes sense given the restriction on OPENROWSET. **But if I convert this to SQL string, won't I lose the ability to set `@RecordType` and `@DataId` from the results of the query?**

Is there any syntactic sugar I can sprinkle on this to get around the restriction and make this work the way I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some examples of building a string dynamically:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314520

You could insert into a table variable first, and then pull your values from there.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (DataID int, RecordType varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t
exec sp_executeSQL N'your OPENROWSERT query'

SELECT TOP 1 @DataID = DataID, @RecordType = RecordType
FROM @t
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Stuart, here is the code that I finally went with:

```
Declare @DataId int
Declare @RecordType varchar(50)
Declare @Filter varchar(50)

Declare @query nvarchar(4000)
 -- ...

select @query = N'select top 1 recordType, DataId
                 from openrowset(''SQLNCLI'', 
                                 ''Server=MyServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
                                 ''SELECT recordType, DataId from MyDb..data_lookup
                                  where Filter = ''''' + @Filter+''''''')'
declare @t TABLE (recordType varchar(2), DataId int)

insert into @t
exec sp_executeSQL @Query

select top 1 @RecordType = recordType, @DataId = DataId
from @t
```